# Partition deallocated

Tags: boot, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I need some urgent help here. I had 3 partitions on my computer, one for windows, the other for ubuntu and the last one for files. I was going to re-install windows and from the windows boot cd I chose to format the partition with the old version. Then after I reboot I noticed that my ubuntu partition was kind of deallocated and I can't access anymore.

I don't think it's a problem with grub. Bellow is the output from fdisk

```
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sda1                *           2048      718847      358400    7 
 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda2          718848   204802047   102041600    7
 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda3       204802048   850450485   322824219    7
 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda4       850452478   976771071    63159297    5
 Extended /dev/sda5       968960000   976771071     3905536   82  Linux
 swap / Solaris

 Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32015679488 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
 3892 cylinders, total 62530624 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
 size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
 0x0008c308

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sdb1   *          63    62524979    31262458+   c  W95 FAT32
 (LBA)
```

Does anybody know how can I at least get my files from the home folder? I don't mind reinstalling ubuntu if I get those files back...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got my partition back!

For those who may come here with a similar problem, I booted with a liveCd, installed *testdisk* and it did the trick, it found and restored my partition!

Now it's all back and I didn't have to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a live CD, Boot in to this and select install. you should then be able to repair your Ubuntu installation.

If you do not have the LiveCD download a new one from the Ubuntu website

Comment: But will I be able to get my files back?